# Use AjaxControlToolKit in ASP.Net 2.0

Tags: ajax

I want to create an application using AjaxAjaxControlToolKit in ASP.Net 2.0
How to use AjaxControlToolKit with ASP.Net 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/releases/view/11121

This version should work for .NET 2.0